# Force shell script to run tasks in sequence

Tags: shell, task

I'm running a shell scripts that executes several tasks. The thing is that the script does not wait for a task to end before starting the next one. My script should work differently, waiting for one task to be completed before the next one to start. Is there a way to do that? My script looks like this

```
sbatch retr.sc 19860101 19860630
scp EN/EN1986* myhostname@myhost.it:/storage/myhostname/MetFiles
```

the first command runs retr.sc, that retrieves files and it takes half an hour roughly. The second command, though, is run right soon, moving just some files to destination. I wish the scp command to be run only when the first is complete.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- use `srun` rather than `sbatch`: `srun retr.sc 19860101 19860630`
- use `sbatch` for the second command as well, and make it depend on the first one

like this:

```
RES=$(sbatch retr.sc 19860101 19860630)   
sbatch --depend=after:${RES##* } --wrap "scp EN/EN1986* myhostname@myhost.it:/storage/myhostname/MetFiles"
```

- create one script that incorporates both `retr.sc` and `scp` and submit that script.

Comment: I get this error when I try your second suggestion: "sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem"

Comment: What exact command line did you run? Did you replace JOBID with the actual job id?

Comment: No I didn't. Both the commands are in a script that takes 19860101 and 19860630 as argument, and I don't know how to make this script to know the JOBID. Is there a way to run sbatch and force it to assign a cspecific JOBID?

Answer (score 0):

sbatch exits immediately on submitting the job to slurm.

salloc will wait for the job to finish before exiting.

from the man page:

```
$ salloc -N16 xterm
salloc: Granted job allocation 65537
(at this point the xterm appears, and salloc waits for xterm to exit)
salloc: Relinquishing job allocation 65537
```

Comment: I cannot use salloc, because it doesn't take a script as argument like sbatch does.

Comment: The man page implies otherwise: "The command may be any program the user wishes. Some typical commands are xterm, a shell script containing srun commands, and srun (see the EXAMPLES section). "

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you replies

I've sorted out this way

```
RES=$(sbatch retr.sc $date1 $date2)
array=(${RES// / })
JOBID=${array[3]}
year1={date1:0:4}
sbatch --dependency=afterok:${JOBID}  scp.sh $year1
```

where scp.sh is the script for transferring the file to my local machine